# crystal report line break with line

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Here's my formula in crystal report

```
StringVar ReplaceString;

ReplaceString := Replace ({command.ExtraPersons}, ",", Chr(10));
ReplaceString
```

Output:

```
Sample One
Sample Two
```

Expected Output must have underline

```
<u>Sample One</u>
<u>Sample Two</u>
```

Thank you,

Comment: Output: Sample One 
             Sample Two
Expected Output: Sample One (with underline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
StringVar ReplaceString;

ReplaceString :="<U>"+ Replace ({command.ExtraPersons}, ",", Chr(10))+"</U>";
ReplaceString
```

Go to format field and on `Paragraph` tab change the text representation to `HTML`

Edit............................................

you can use `ChrW(13)` to get new line.

Comment: Hi Siva, thank you so much for the quick response by the way, I'm using c#.net not HTML sorry to use <u></u> :) i'm new to crystal reports and c#.net aspiring software engr. :)

Comment: You can accept it as answered so that others can use. check my edited answer for new line